# How to store post meta in an array?

Tags: post-meta, array

What is the best way to store post meta in an array (using a custom write box, know how to do that) so that all post meta is in a single custom field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From codex:

> $meta_value (mixed) (required) The
>   value of the custom field you will
>   add. An array will be serialized into
>   a string. Default: None

So  `<?php add_post_meta(7, 'fruit', 'banana', 'apple', 'tornado', 'bob saget')`

To grab them you can also use http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_values

besides just `get_post_meta`.